# MS Dynamics CRM Plugin Error - [A]CrmWebSvc cannot be cast to [B]CrmWebSvc

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to create a simple Dynamics CRM plugin to create multiple entity association using Microsoft's XRM Tooling. I'm instantiating this class this way:

```
public class PartnerPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public static IOrganizationService staticservice;
    string log = string.Empty;
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        CrmServiceClient crmService = new CrmServiceClient((OrganizationServiceProxy)serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId));
       ...
    }
}
```

It's almost the same code of another that i already have registered at CRM but this time it's giving me that error:

> [A]Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.
>   Type A originates from 'plab_quote, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=567d876020387fa5' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a
>   byte array. Type B originates from 'quotePartners, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4f3d8ebbe2fb8cfb' in the context
>   'LoadNeither' in a byte array. If you contact support, please provide
>   the technical
>   details.

The thing is that, after a lot of tests i just put these 3 lines of code (IPluginExecutionContext context = (...) CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId)))
and nothing. Same error.
I'm using Dynamics CRM 365

Another strange thing: I already had this error but, (i swear) i just took 5 minutes for a coffee and when i came back to try again the error was gone.
I tried some coffee again but it's not working. Nothing's working.

Anyone? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugin has two fields, `staticservice` and `log`.

Both fields (static as well as instance) are not thread safe. For every plugin class-stage-mode combination the system creates an instance that is being used for multiple, eventually concurrent events.

Race conditions will cause threads overwriting eachother's fields, which leads to unexpected results.

Comment: i just got what you said :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that the problem is that i had already instancialized a variable with same name in another plugin with same step!
That is the error :)